# Installing Ubuntu on Acer Aspire One D150-1Bb

Tags: system-installation

I have an **Acer Aspire One D150-1Bb**. It came with Windows XP installed. I wish to use Ubuntu in it.

Do I need to partition the HDD, or any other preparation, or is it all dealt with automatically with the download?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to install Ubuntu into separate partition for that create two logical partition in windows, one for ubuntu os and other is swap partition(size should be at-least your ram memory size eg: if you have 1GB ram create swap with 1GB or 2GB) and you can install into your created partition for ubuntu by selecting "something else" during installation(very important)

Here is how to install step by step it works for any version of ubuntu http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/step-by-step-beginners-guide-to-installing-ubuntu-11-10.172128/

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you need to install Ubuntu seperately

But if you're new to Ubuntu as well as Linux, you should be careful since a mistake can blow your data away. Except for the case you don't need Windows anymore, you should use [wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide). It'll install Ubuntu in a disk image alongside with windows with a windows dualboot menu instead of Linux Grub boot menu

Answer (score 0):

If you want ubuntu in dual boot you should create a partition but if you want to replace windows XP you dont need to create a partition.
If you want to install inside windows you dont need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to download Ubuntu from it's [official download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it to a clean DVD disk or use software like [DriveDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softwarebakery.drivedroid).

After that, turn off your computer and insert Ubuntu disc you've burnt. Enter **boot menu** in your laptop and select **CD-ROM Drive**.[image: Source: www.prosofteng.com/support/images/mtw_boot_menu.jpg]

Your laptop should be booting to Ubuntu now. From there, you can try Ubuntu, or install it. You don't have to worry about creating partitions etc. as Ubuntu installer will ask you, what to do.

[image: Installer]